# My attempt at $f''(x)+\sin(f'(x))=0$ does it work?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, indefinite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

Here's an attempt at a fairly innocent-looking separable differential equation.
$$f''(x)+\sin f'(x)=0$$
$$\int\frac{f''(x)}{\sin f'(x)}dx=-(x+c)$$
let $y=f'(x)$ then $dy=f''(x)dx$
$$\int\csc y\,dy=-(x+c)$$
$$-\ln|\csc y+\cot y|=-(x+c)$$
$$\csc y+\cot y=e^{x+c}$$
let $a=e^{x+c}$, $w=\sin y$
$$\frac{1}{w}+\frac{\sqrt{1-w^2}}{w}=a$$
$$1+\sqrt{1-w^2}=aw$$
$$a^2w^2=1+2\sqrt{1-w^2}+1-w^2$$
$$w^2(a^2+1)=2\biggl(1+\sqrt{1-w^2}\biggr)$$
$$w^2(a^2+1)=2aw$$
$$w=\frac{2a}{a^2+1}$$
$$f'(x)=\arcsin\biggr(\frac{2a}{a^2+1}\biggl)$$
$$f(x)=\int\arcsin\biggr(\frac{2e^{x+c}}{e^{2(x+c)}+1}\biggl)dx$$
Which is a pretty nasty integral. Does this solution work? I know there is an elementary-ish form of the integral (given [here](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=arcsin%28%282e%5E%28x%2Bc%29%29%2F%28e%5E%282%28x%2Bc%29%29%2B1%29%29)) but I want to know if I can represent this with a series or hypergeometric function.

Comment: Approach is perfectly fine (I did not verify your final result, but you can leave as-is). **Note:** You can always check your result by plugging it back into the DEQ and verifying it works.

Comment: @Moo thanks. I tried plugging in, but there was too much nasty algebra. I think I'll do that once I feel like I have the brain power.